# What would cause a weed-eater to suddenly only run on partial choke?

Tags: small-engine, choke

As stated in question - was starting and running beautifully until this past usage.  Same fuel I've been using and same storage method.  Suddenly will only run on mid-choke.  Even after using for 10 minutes and soon as you move to the "run" position it basically dies immediately.

Comment: Sounds like a needle jet is clogged, probably by some grass or dirt which you got in the gas tank, or which had been sitting at the bottom of the tank until disturbed. I'd recommend you dismantle the carburetor (a fairly simple task on most small engines) and blow out the valves and other lines with compressed air.

Comment: Could first try spraying some carb cleaner Into the carburettor air intake.

Comment: Be careful using compressed air on weedeater carburetors, too much pressure can damage them.

Comment: You might check the spark suppressor screen.  It plugs with oil in the exhaust; worse if you run at part throttle. When it's plugged, it robs power, and the engine runs badly.  Usually, there's a bolt in the exhaust port.  If it's gummed up, I burn the oil off with a propane torch.